# React router depending on the state of the React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with react-router.

My routes file is as follows :

```
const routes = (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="registration" component={Registration}>
        <Route path="/registration-step-one" component={RegistrationStepOne} />
        <Route path="/registration-step-two" component={RegistrationStepTwo}/>
        <Route path="/registration-step-three" component={RegistrationStepThree}/>
        <Route path="/registration-step-four" component={RegistrationStepFour}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="reset-password" component={PasswordReset} />
</Route>
);
```

I have one big component **Registration** which has four steps. And by click on the submit button the state changes and the next step shows.

Registration component code is :

```
onButtonClick(name, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch (name) {
        case "stepFourConfirmation":
            this.setState({step: 1});
            break;
        case "stepTwoNext":
            this.setState({step: 3, errors: {}});
            break;
        case "stepThreeFinish":
            this.setState({step: 4});
            break;
        default:
            this.setState({step: 2, errors: {}});
    }
}

render() {
    const languageReg = this.props.currentLanguage.default.registrationPage;

    let formStep = '';
    let step = this.state.step;
    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepOne user={this.state.user}
                                                 onChange={this.setUser}
                                                 onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                 onClick={this.changeStep}
                                                 errors={this.state.errors}/>);
            break;
        case 2:
            formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepTwo user={this.state.user}
                                                 onChange={this.setUser}
                                                 onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                 onClick={this.changeStep}
                                                 errors={this.state.errors}/>);
            break;
        case 3:
            formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepThree user={this.state.user}
                                                   onFileChange={this.onFileChange}
                                                   onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                   onClick={this.changeStep}
                                                   errors={this.state.errors}
                                                   files={this.state.files}
                                                   fileChosen={this.state.selectedFile}/>);
            break;

        default:
            formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepFour user={this.state.user}
                                                  onChange={this.setUser}

                                                  onChangeCheckboxState={this.changeCheckboxState}
                                                  emailNotificationsState={this.state.user.emailNotifications}
                                                  termsState={this.state.user.terms}
                                                  smsNotificationsState={this.state.user.smsNotifications}

                                                  onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                  onClick={this.changeStep}
                                                  errors={this.state.errors}/>);
    }

    return (
        <div className="sidebar-menu-container" id="sidebar-menu-container">

            <div className="sidebar-menu-push">

                <div className="sidebar-menu-overlay"></div>

                <div className="sidebar-menu-inner">
                    <div className="contact-form">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-offset-right-1">
                                    {React.cloneElement(formStep, {currentLanguage: languageReg})}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But if I'm on a for example third step and I click back in the browser I'm redirected to the home page. Is there any way that react router goes only to the previous step ant not to the homepage? Or it can't be done if I use states to change the form step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the `routerWillLeave` hook. Read more about it on the [official react-router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md).

Here's what you could do:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
  //or this.context.router, depending on your app
}

routerWillLeave = (nextLocation) => {
  if (this.state.step > 1) {
    this.setState({step: this.state.step-1});
    return false;
  }
}
```

The above will prevent route change if the `step` change is greater than one. Instead `setState` is called and `step` is reduced by 1, forcing a render of the previous step. If `step` is equal to 1, then it probably makes sense to actually go back in the history to the previous page, since there is no previous step before step-1.

---

You might also be interested in asking for a route-leave confirmation dialog before actually going back to the previous page if the user has filled in some data in your form (to prevent it from being lost). In that case you could add to the above code:

```
routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
  if (this.state.step > 1) {
    ...
  } else if (this.hasUnsavedData()) {
    return "You have unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave?"
  }
```

Where `hasUnsavedData()` some custom function you would write that checks all your form elements and returns `false` only if all input fields are empty, otherwise `true`.

Comment: I'm getting _TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRouteLeaveHook' of undefined_

Comment: I've added `RegistrationPage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};` to make context available. But now I get _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined_ .

Comment: Okay, try using an ES6 function. Replace `routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {` with `routerWillLeave = (nextLocation) => {`

Comment: I placed everything in componentDidMount `componentDidMount() {
        this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, (nextLocation) => {

            if (this.state.step > 1) {
                this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1});
                return false;
            }

        });
    }` Now i get warning do not use setState in componentDidMount but it worked. :)

Comment: Glad it worked, but why not split the 2 functions like I suggested above? Why everything under `componentDidMount`?

Comment: I've got an error. Unexpected = in `routerWillLeave = (nextLocation) => {` . But it worked like on the first answer, I did only `this.routerWillLeave = this.routerWillLeave.bind(this);` in constructor. Thanks mate ;)

Comment: Not sure how your whole app works, but you'll probably need to store all the form data somewhere top-level where all your step-components can access. Probably in your registration component. Whenever you load a new step, check if there already exists relevant data for that step, and if so, load it.

Comment: And when I pass data via state `this.state.user` everything works nice, but when I try to pass the data via the redux `this.props.userData` the data isn't showing although I see in debugger that this.props.useeData has a value which I need.

Comment: @Boky, it sounds like you might have a **new** issue that's not related to this particular question about history. Post a new question :)

Comment: Now I have I problem when I click on the logo if I'm on for example third step. Now when I click on the logo it's the same like that I've clicked on the back button. I'm not redirected to the homepage.

Comment: @Boky, add variables to check what element you clicked. If it's a *not* a button that takes you to the next/previous step, then *do not* enter `routerWillLeave` at all. Please, if you need more help, post a new question with a reference/link to this post. I'll not be answering more questions in the comments - only in new post :)

Comment: Ok, I'll do it now.

Comment: I've added I new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727739/redirect-to-the-homepage-with-react-router) . Can you help me?