# Redirect to the homepage with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I few hours ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723991/react-router-depending-on-the-state-of-the-react-component/37724717?noredirect=1#comment62925278_37724717), and everything worked fine.
But the problem is when I click on the logo when I'm on a for example third step, I'm redirected to the second step in place of the homepage.

Any idea how to avoid that and when I click on the logo that it redirects me to the home page no matter on which step I am.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `routerWillLeave` hook will always kick in now whenever you do something that will cause a Route change. Since you only want this special behavior when navigating between your Steps, you could add some sort of a `flag` variable to determine if you want the "normal" behavior or not.

Try this:

```
routerWillLeave = (nextLocation) => {
  if (this.state.step > 1 && this.flag) {
    this.setState({step: this.state.step-1});
    this.flag = false; // <-- reset the flag.
    return false;
  }
  this.flag = false; // <-- reset the flag.
}
```

I added the `&& this.flag` to your code, meaning that the `step` needs to be greater than 1 **and** the `flag` needs to be `true` in order for `step` to decrease.

To actually set the flag, set it to true whenever the buttons that change `step` are clicked.

```
onButtonClick(name, event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.flag = true; // <-- We clicked on button; set flag to true
   switch (name) {
     case "stepFourConfirmation":
        this.setState({step: 1});
        break;
     case "stepTwoNext":
        this.setState({step: 3, errors: {}});
        break;
     case "stepThreeFinish":
        this.setState({step: 4});
        break;
     default:
        this.setState({step: 2, errors: {}});
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is if I click on Next the flag is set to true and I'm on a second step. And when I than click on logo, the flag is still true and `routerWillLeave` will execute the if statement because the step is greater than 1 and the flag is true, and it redirects me to the previous step.

Comment: You're right. The reset of the flag needs to be moved a bit. I'll update the code.

Comment: @Boky I perhaps you need to move the code into your `onClick` function instead. I don't have your full code. But the solution here is easy, it's only a matter of setting your `flag` to `true` when a button is clicked **and** reset it to `false` inside your `routerWillLeave` function. Play around with it a bit, I'm sure you'll find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to validate if nextLocation is '/' and return true:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
  //or this.context.router, depending on your app
}

routerWillLeave = (nextLocation) => {
  if(nextLocation === '/') {
    return true;
  }

  if (this.state.step > 1) {
    this.setState({step: this.state.step-1});
    return false;
  }
}
```